# Tabs and independent scroll positions

Tags: jquery, css, scroll, tabs, materialize

I'm currently using https://materializecss.com/tabs.html library with my project.

Unfortunately I have a tiny niggle that's causing a few issues.

I have 4 tabs all of which are filled with content, now when i go to scroll down to bottom of the content for tab 1 and then click to go to tab 2 the scroll position is at the bottom as it was for tab 1.

My understanding that the tabs would have their own individual scroll positions and would remember their state when switching tabs.

I'm at a bit of a loss what to try here unless I add a fixed position div inside each tab?

```
 <div class="row">
   <div class="col s12">
    <ul class="tabs">
      <li class="tab col s3"><a href="#test1">Test 1</a></li>
      <li class="tab col s3"><a class="active" href="#test2">Test 2</a></li>
      <li class="tab col s3"><a href="#test3">Disabled Tab</a></li>
      <li class="tab col s3"><a href="#test4">Test 4</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div id="test1" class="col s12">Test 1</div>
  <div id="test2" class="col s12">Test 2</div>
  <div id="test3" class="col s12">Test 3</div>
  <div id="test4" class="col s12">Test 4</div>
 </div>
```

Each tab would have its own scroll position

Comment: Can you please provide a full working code on JSfiddle or Codepen?

Comment: please add your javascript/jquery version and css to the question